# Refused to display 'https://www.google.co.in' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: jquery, iframe, bootstrap-modal

I try to load external url in my iframe but it loads nothing. it just give me error : refused to display one drive page in a frame because it set 'x-frame-options' to 'sameorigin'.

```
    <html>
    <head>    
    <title>Iframe Test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2> Welcome 2 My Site </h2>
    <CENTER>
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><iframe src="http://www.google.com" height="400" width="100%"></iframe> </td>
</tr>
</table></CENTER>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the url ????? Your iframe src field is empty .

Comment: sorry... i update the questions